# Mocha ES6 Babel "TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, mocha.js

I'm currently trying to implement simple tests for my JavaScript components and I am getting the error: `TypeError: undefined is not a function` from my test.

This is erroring on this line within my class:

`this.options = Object.assign({}, this.defaults, options);`

`this.defaults` is an object of default options and `options` is currently an object with nothing in.

I am running the code from CLI using `npm test` which resolves to this: `mocha ./src/components/myComponent/myComponent.spec.js --compilers js:babel-register`

Does anyone know why this error occurs?

Comment: Maybe you need to install [babel-plugin-transform-object-assign](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-assign/)

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH - this worked! Thank you, can you write this as the answer and I will up-vote it?

Comment: Answer added ;) you are welcome & good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Babel needs a plugin in order to transform `Object.assign`, please try to install [babel-plugin-transform-object-assign](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-assign/).

Answer (score 0):

What version of node are you running with? Object.assign won't be available throughout. You might want to use object-assign package

```
const assign = require('object-assign');
...
this.options = assign({}, this.defauts, options)
```

Comment: The error is coming from the console on the test and it is complaining about the line within my javascript class, not the test itself